# Developing mobile web applications

Tags: .net, mobile

What's the most well maintained and recommended framework to use with .net when developing mobile web applications?

Answer (score 1):

that's difficult to answer if you don't explain the purpose and features of the application.

Comment: I'm looking for a framework like asp.net mvc that's targeting mobi sites.

Answer (score 0):

There is none that I know of. I created a cms for mobile content using Dynamic Data Entities WebApplication Project for managing the content with CKEditor, a regular asp.net webapplication for handling the portals AND [wurfl](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/) as detection of handsets.

The CMS handles about 50 domains.